# adding tuples to a list in an if loop (python)

Tags: python

I'm working in python with symbulate for a probability course and running some simulations.

Setup: Two teams, A and B, are playing in a “best of n” game championship series, where n is an odd number. For this example, n=7, and the probability team A wins any individual game is 0.55. Approximate the probability that Team A wins the series, given that they win the first game.

Here is what I've got so far, which I think is along the right lines:

```
model = BoxModel([1, 0], probs=[0.55, .45], size=7, replace=True)
test = model.sim(10000)

for x in range(0,10000):
    test1 = test[x]

    if test1[0] == 1:
         print (test1)

test1
```

The last two lines are where I'm having my difficulty. This 'for' and 'if' combination makes it so only the inputs that start with a '1' (i.e. Team A winning the first game) are displayed. I need to save these inputs into a table so that I can run some further testing on it.

How do I input the value of test1 into a table while those loops are running? Currently, test1 only outputs the x=10,000th value.

Edit: The "test" yields a list, 0-10000, of all the possible game outcomes.  I need a list that only has the game outcomes that start with a "1".

Edit2: Output of "test" (before I run a "for" or "if") look like:

```
Index   Result

0   (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
1   (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
2   (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
3   (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
4   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
5   (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
6   (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
7   (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
8   (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
... ...
9999    (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

I need a "test' (or another variable) to contain something that looks EXACTLY like that, but only contains lines that start with "1".

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking to store the results of each test? Why not store them in a `list`?

```
test1_results = []

for x in range(0,10000):
    test1 = test[x]
    # check if first element in sequence of game outcomes is a win for team A
    if test1[0] == 1:    # or '1' if you're expecting string
        test1_results.append(test1)
```

You can the run `print(test1_results)` to print the entire list of results, but if you want to print the first `n` results, do `print(test1_results[:n])`.

If you want your `if` statement in there, you will have to slightly adjust the placement. What does your `test` object look like? Could you give us a small sample?

edit: updated `if` statement to reflect comment below

Comment: The "test" yields a list, 0-10000, of all the possible game outcomes.  I need a list that only has the game outcomes that start with a "1".

I am using the "if" statement to only grab the lines of "test" that start with a "1". But I can't get the results of my "if" to store in another variable. Does that help?

Comment: I updated above. Does that give you your desired result? It would be **really** great if you literally included in your code above a piece of the actual possible game outcomes object. If it's a list, something like `print(test[:10])` would give you the output, then paste that into your question

Comment: Working on trying to include game outcomes in my OP right now. formatting is killing me. thank you for your help!

Comment: think i got it. is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes, updated my answer. you might also want to keep the index of each `test1` you append, something like `test1_results.append((x, test1))`. Up to you.

Comment: the "append" seems to be what i was looking for. I'm gonna work with it for a minute nd get back to you. you're my super hero :D

Comment: I would just recommend that you get out of the habit of iterating over the range of 0,10000 and instead just iterate over the items in results.  IE instead of `for x in range(0,10000)`, just `for x in test`.  This will return the individual elements without you specifying the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

```
results_that_start_with_one = []

for result in test:
     result_string = str(result)
     if result_string[0] == "1":
         results_that_start_with_one.append(result_string)
```

This iterates through each of your results in the list "test".  It convert each to a string (i'm assuming they are some numeric value).  It then takes the first character in the string, and asks if its a 1.

Comment: The "test" yields a list, 0-10000, of all the possible game outcomes.  I need a list that only has the game outcomes that start with a "1". Does that make more sense?

Comment: Ahhh ok.  Lemme change my asnwer